how to install Kafk-connect,use curl have not message
enter image description here
The connect-distributed.properties of Kafka on one host and two slaves are written like this
enter image description here
And I placed these two jar packages under the plugins file. But it can't be displayed
enter image description here
I used  directive./bin/connect-distributed.sh /path/to/connect-distributed.properties &
I started slave1 and slave2, but they both reported errors.
WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:750)

This is how I configured it in server.properties（slave1\slave2）
listeners = PLAINTEXT://slave1:9092
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
#listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.245.129:9092


Please clarify what cannot be displayed
